# XMLSchema - Element refers to itself - how to do it?

Tags: reference, xsd

I have a task where I need to create an element "Worker" which has 0 or more subelements "subordinate". I have to use key and keyref to create the references. I can't figure out how make the references "work". Here's what I've written so far:

```
<xsd:element name="Workers">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Worker" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>

                        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                        <xsd:element name="subordinate" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="identyfikator" type="PESEL" use="required"/>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:key name="id">
        <xsd:selector xpath="Worker"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@identyfikator"/>
    </xsd:key>

    <xsd:keyref name="subordinate_ref" refer="id">
        <xsd:selector xpath="Worker/subordinate"/>
        <xsd:field xpath="@identyfikator"/>
    </xsd:keyref>   
</xsd:element>
```

PESEL is my own type and the key restriction works well as I am unable to create two workers with the same key in XML document. However, I can create anything as "subordinate" element and no warnings will be displayed. As I understand, in case of such reference I should be only able to add workers as subordinates if they already exist, right? How do I create proper reference? 
This is my first time working with XMLSchema so sorry if the code is messy.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make a `Worker` ComplexType and have `Worker` and `Subordinate` both be of that type.

Approximately like so:

```
<!-- Define the below where appropriate. -->
<xsd:element name="Worker" type="WorkerType" />

<xsd:complexType name="WorkerType">
    <xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="subordinate" type="WorkerType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>

    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="identyfikator" type="PESEL" use="required"/>

</xsd:complexType>
```

Also, if you want items to have a unique id, then consider using (or extending) the [`xsd:ID` datatype](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_ID.html). This gives you free uniqueness and referential checks using `xsd:IDREF`.

```
    <xsd:attribute name="identyfikator" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>
```